# Adding a UIScrollView to an existing UIView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard, scrollview

I build an app using storyboards and I want to embed one of the view in a UIScrollView. Therefore to do so, I drag an drop the UIScrollView directly in the storyboard. I then adapt it size and position.

After that I select all my items and drag and drop them into the UIScrollView. My problem is that all my items' positions get messed up: they all align in the center of the UIScrollView so I have to reposition them myself.

Is there any way I can keep the same layout?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to select the view, then go to editor -> embed in -> scroll view.

For more complex things, temporarily disable autolayout, create a new empty viewcontroller, copy/paste all your subitems there, do your voodoo with your scrollview, paste them back when it's done.

Comment: This is helpful. However, all the constraints between the embedded views and the root view are lost. I guess there is no way to save them.